# Automatic phone dialing application for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios7, telephony, iphone-privateapi

I am trying to develop an application that can dial phone numbers at regular intervals from iPhone without user interaction. The problem is when the phone dialer app comes to foreground then my app goes to background.

I tried using web view to call the phone number but it prompts for the user before calling the number. Is there any way to to dial a number from webview without prompting user?

or is there any other work around to get my application to foreground after call ends.

My app is not going to app store so private api is not a problem.

Edit: I tried using the teleprompt:// but I need no user interaction. I also cannot jail break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS7 you can't make phone calls from regular iOS apps. By that I mean calling `CTCallDial` to dial a phone number without user permission.

Background/foreground. Your app will move to the background and you can't do anything about it. If you want you could let your app run in the background without suspending. For that you need to add `audio` background mode and loop silent audio file. If you don't need UI you can continue execute your tasks while in background. If you need UI there is a workaround - post local notification to let user resume your app after phone call ends. You could also try to invoke phone dialer UI from the background. I didn't tried it but it may be possible.

Comment: I am using following method [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
Tried using both tel:// and telPrompt:// but both do not work while in background.

Answer (score 0):

Apple isn't providing this type of facility. Apple insist that you need user permissions at all the steps. If you want to call then you must need user permission OR provide user interface to call the no.

And you will implement your suggested functionality but apple will reject your application.
but according to you that your app will not going to AppStore.

I don't know about NSTimer. Try to use this.

iOS doesn't provide come back to our app's foreground state from apple default apps.